# Add previous and next functions for slideshow with window.onload JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to create a JavaScript program who allow the user to switch between
image by using previous and next button. But i can't use window.onload to load  the next image cause window.onload overwrite the previous window.onload. I want to know if their exist any solution to make window.onload work with two functions in the same time. If window.onload can't be usable for this kind of program you can suggest me another solution.
Thank you.

```
var i =0;
var image = [];
 image[0]= 'image.jpg';
 image[1]= 'image2.jpg';
 image[2]= 'panther.jpg'
function next(){
    document.slide.src = image[i];
    if(i<image.length-1){
     i++;
    }
    else{
    i=0;
    }
document.getElementById('bouton1').addEventListener('click',next);
}
function previous(){
    document.slide.src = image[i];
    if(i>0){
    i--;    
    }
    else{
    i=image.length-1;   
    }
document.getElementById('bouton2').addEventListener('click',previous);
}

window.onload =  next;
    window.onload = previous;
```

Comment: can you explain a bit in depth what do you want to do exactly on window load?

Comment: when i write  window.onload = next; and after window.onload = previous;  the next() function won't run  cause window.onload was overwrited i want to find a solution to make all function in my code usable even if i use window.onload to display my slideshow.

Answer (score 0):

Needed a couple of changes, can you test it like this. Note we changed the onload to attach listeners. See comment.

```
var i =0;
var image = [];
 image[0]= 'image.jpg';
 image[1]= 'image2.jpg';
 image[2]= 'panther.jpg'
function next(){
    document.slide.src = image[i];
    if(i<image.length-1){
     i++;
    }
    else{
    i=0;
    }

}
function previous(){
    document.slide.src = image[i];
    if(i>0){
    i--;    
    }
    else{
    i=image.length-1;   
    }

}

// This is window.onload
(function(){
  // Move calls to attach event listeners here
  document.getElementById('bouton2').addEventListener('click',previous);
  document.getElementById('bouton1').addEventListener('click',next);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure about your idea behind `window.onload`, if you want to preload images (so the user does not have to wait for the image to load on buttons click...) than you could use `new Image()` and something like:

```js
const EL_slide = document.getElementById("slide");
const EL_prev = document.getElementById('prev');
const EL_next = document.getElementById('next');
const image = [
  '//placehold.it/800x600/0bf?text=1',
  '//placehold.it/800x600/f0b?text=2',
  '//placehold.it/800x600/0fb?text=3'
];
const n = image.length;
let i = 0;

// Preload images
image.forEach(src => { 
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = src;
});

// Animation logic
function anim() {
  if((/prev|next/).test(this.id)) i = this.id === "next" ? ++i : --i;
  i = i<0 ? n-1 : i%n; // Index fixer (prevents out of bound index)
  EL_slide.style.backgroundImage = `url('${image[i]}')`
}

// Events
[EL_prev, EL_next].forEach(EL => EL.addEventListener('click', anim));

// Load first!
anim();
```

```css
#slide {
  height: 70vh;
  transition: 0.3s;
  background: none 50% 50% / cover no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<button id="prev">&larr;</button>
<button id="next">&rarr;</button>
<div id="slide"></div>
```

and just make sure to place your Javascript right before the closing `</body>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

`addEventListener` is a better method for adding an event handler without replacing an existing one.

```
window.addEventListener('load', e => { /* ... */ });
```

As a rule of thumb, any `on(blah)` attributes in the DOM can be replaced with `addEventListener(blah, ...)`.